# Cannot read property replace of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is code sample:

```
amountVal = SetAmount(amountVal).replace(/,/g, "");
var lenght = parseInt((amountVal.length - 4) / 3);
var rest = amountVal.substring(amountVal.length - 3);
var main = amountVal.substring(0, amountVal.length - 3);
```

In first line when i try to run script it throw exception:

> Cannot read property replace of undefined.

It works fine for integers, but throw this err when try to use decimal. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Your `SetAmount()` function is not returning a value. We would need to see the code of that function, as well as the value of `amountVal` to help you

Comment: I don;t think replace will work like this .replace('/,/g', ""); it should like this

Comment: Can you show your SetAmount function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems *SetAmount(amountVal)* method returns undefined. If not then can you please share the result of this method.
E.g. you may have a look by running the below code in console:

> undefined.replace(/,/g, "")